# Want to compare two columns of different table in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I want to compare two columns from two different tables, I have column called "Features" in Model Attrition_correlators and another "Topcorrelators" in Membersdetail.
Since I am new to laravel not sure how I can get the value and compare both values.
Here is my code:

Controller.php

```html
public function show(Memberdetails $Memberdetail, Attrition_correlators $Attrition_correlation_list)
    {
        
        return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('Memberdetail','Attrition_correlation_list'));
    }
```

```html
 <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      @foreach(explode(',', $Memberdetail->Topcorrelators) as $row)
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ $row }}
        </td>
         @if($Attrition_correlation_list->Features == $Memberdetail->Topcorrelators)
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        @else
        <td>
          0
        </td>
        @endif
   </tr>
   @endforeach
```

I want to compare the data which I am getting $row with the values in "features" if they match Want to get the value of correlation which is in Model "Attrition_correlators" under .
Can anyone help me out in this!
Thanks in Advance
Below is the error I am getting
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why you use ```$Attrition_correlators= new Attrition_correlators;```  
 ```$Attrition_correlation_list= $Attrition_correlators::all();``` in your controller, please? Because you passed ```$Attrition_correlation_list``` as parameter in your method

Comment: And please show your ```Attrition_correlators``` model's tables

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attrition_correlators', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->id();
            $table->string('Features');
            $table->string('Correlation Value');
            $table->string('Positive/Negative Correlation');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: @MohammadHosseini I was trying that's reason else I have removed it from my original code

Comment: @MohammadHosseini Can You please help me out in this...I have updated the snippet. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you get a collection of Attrition_correlation_list. In this case you need to iterate over it to get properties:

```
@foreach(explode(',', $Memberdetail->Topcorrelators) as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $row }}
        </td>
        @foreach($Attrition_correlation_list as $item)
            @if($item->Features == $row)
            ...
            @else
            ...
            @endif
        @endforeach
   </tr>
   @endforeach
```

You also need to edit your controller like below. Because you passed null value in `$Attrition_correlation_list`

```
public function show(Memberdetails $Memberdetail)
    {
        $Attrition_correlation_list = Attrition_correlators::all();
        return view('admin.members.Detailspage',compact('Memberdetail','Attrition_correlation_list'));
    }
```

Comment: No I don't Have commas between the Features column value and I have already tried the above solution it's not working for me give me same error the Trying to get property 'Features' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Attrition_Test\resources\views\admin\members\Detailspage.blade.php)

Comment: When I am trying to return only $Attrition_correlation_list from Show() it gives me blank array

Comment: @prashant what about ```$Memberdetail```?It has values? Can you share one sample of ```$Memberdetail``` object please?

Comment: Yes So I have resource controller MemberdetailController and I am getting aal the values from table...now there is column with id on this click it should load a new view where I want to show the details of that particular id, now this table from where I am getting values in Members table have column "Topcorrelators" now I have second table Which is Attrition_correlators in which "Feature" column have all topcorrelators with values. Now what exactly I want to check if All the values from Top correlators for particular id and Features match if they match it should display it's value

Comment: This is my MemberdetailController index function

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $Memberdetails= new Memberdetails;
        $Memberdetails_list= $Memberdetails::all();
        return view('admin.members.Datapoints',compact('Memberdetails_list'));
    }

Comment: `@foreach($Memberdetails_list as $d)
   <tr>
      <td>
       <a href="/Memberdetails/{{ $d->id }}">{{ $d->membersid }}</a>
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ $d->Role}}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ $d->Region}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $d->Orglevel1}}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ $d->Orglevel2}}
      </td>
      <td>`

Comment: Sorry for the format I am really new in this forum, as you can see I am redirecting to new view where I want more details about membersid and also it's topcorrelators with value which is in another table

Comment: Could this be beacuse the is no relation between tables...?

Comment: @prashant I have edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: I have tried this as well still same error the way Iam doing is it correct? Maybe when i click on members id it redirects to new view where I am get info with id do I need to do something with routes like Attrition_correlators/{Features} new like in members detail I have passed{ id} to get details.. not sur I am correct or not but stuck with this for couple of days now

Comment: <a href="/Memberdetails/{{ $d->id  }}

Comment: I have made some changes to Model added few more entries previously it was working fine with code you have shared...but again it's returning blank